# ST_Difference in PostGIS : problem with geometry result (Polygon)

Tags: postgis, topology, function

I'm experimenting a result issue using the ST_Difference spatial function in PostGIS.

**Input :**

Feature 1 and 2 overlaps each other. Both contains 5 vertices, like a rectangle (4 plus an additional one to close the polygon).

I want to get the geometry difference between feature 2 and feature 1. (st_difference(geom(feature2),geom(feature1))

[image: input]

**Result :**

After executing the function, the result of geom(feature2)-geom(feature1), in green, contains unexpected residual vertices (highlighted), inside feature 1 :

[image: difference]

**Result only :**

[image: result]

Anyone knows how to avoid this issue, or how to get a "cleaned" difference of 2 input polygons?

---

The input data is Polygon, the result (after st_difference) is multipolygon. I  get the same result with Polygon geometry for the result.

Input :
[image]

Result :

[image]

Edit 2 :

Input polygon geometry :

Feature 1 :

"POLYGON((363011.683640322 5784798.67947383,363061.369728361 5784794.01684973,363060.058365334 5784774.34640432,363009.64374228 5784780.75751245,363011.683640322 5784798.67947383))"

Feature 2 :

"POLYGON((363079.583103742 5784786.58579258,363079.583103742 5784777.55195839,363053.501550197 5784780.32039144,363054.230085212 5784789.06281163,363079.583103742 5784786.58579258))"

Result of st_difference(feature2(geom),feature1(geom)) :

MULTIPOLYGON(((363079.583103742 5784786.58579258,363079.583103742 5784777.55195839,363053.501550197 5784780.32039144,363060.407760381 5784779.58733003,363060.995393925 5784788.40183319,363054.230085212 5784789.06281163,363079.583103742 5784786.58579258)))

As shown on the screenshot, the result contains 7 vertices (instead of 5 as expected).

CRS : 28355

Comment: Can you share the data needed to reproduce this?

Comment: It seems to me like your geometries are not actually polygons, but just their boundaries. Can you confirm this ? If it's true, you can run a ST_MakePolygon, or ST_Polygonize before you do the differences.

Comment: I just add an edit with data screenshots. I'm happy to share the data too. Should I upload the shp file and add a hyperlink on the post?

Comment: Easiest is to just post the result of st_astext(geom). If it is only 2 polygons with 5 vertex points that is the best.

Comment: I have just added a post update containing the wkt geometry. thanks for your help

Comment: using postgis 2.4, it returns a polygon with 5 vertices as expected

Comment: `WITH geoms(g1, g2) AS (VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((363011.683640322 5784798.67947383,363061.369728361 5784794.01684973,363060.058365334 5784774.34640432,363009.64374228 5784780.75751245,363011.683640322 5784798.67947383))'), ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((363079.583103742 5784786.58579258,363079.583103742 5784777.55195839,363053.501550197 5784780.32039144,363054.230085212 5784789.06281163,363079.583103742 5784786.58579258))')))
SELECT ST_NPoints(ST_Difference(g2, g1)) from geoms;` does indeed return a polygon with 5 vertices.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given in a comment. Issue must have been in some old PostGIS version. Like PostGIS 2.4 five years ago, PostGIS 3.4 returns a polygon with 5 vertices. The computed vertices differ a bit, though.

```
select ST_AsText(
ST_Difference(
ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON((363079.583103742 5784786.58579258,363079.583103742 5784777.55195839,363053.501550197 5784780.32039144,363054.230085212 5784789.06281163,363079.583103742 5784786.58579258))'
),ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON((363011.683640322 5784798.67947383,363061.369728361 5784794.01684973,363060.058365334 5784774.34640432,363009.64374228 5784780.75751245,363011.683640322 5784798.67947383))'
)));
```

Output:

```
POLYGON((363079.583103742 5784777.55195839,363060.407760381 5784779.587330026,363060.9953939253 5784788.401833192,363079.583103742 5784786.58579258,363079.583103742 5784777.55195839))
```